# WCF service hosted in azure worker role returns 400 (Bad Request) error

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have hosted wcf service in worker role on http port and i iopen that port onStart method as given bellow in code

```
public override bool OnStart()
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

            CreateServiceHost();

            return base.OnStart();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 

    }

    private ServiceHost serviceHost;
    private void CreateServiceHost()
    {
        //serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));

        //WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None);
        //RoleInstanceEndpoint externalEndPoint =
        //    RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["ServiceEP"];
        //string endpoint = String.Format("http://{0}/Service",
        //    externalEndPoint.IPEndpoint);

        //serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, endpoint);

        //serviceHost.Open();


        var endpoint = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["ServiceEP"];
        var ub = new UriBuilder();
        ub.Host = endpoint.IPEndpoint.Address.ToString();
        ub.Port = endpoint.IPEndpoint.Port;
        ub.Scheme = "http";
        ub.Path = "Service";
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), ub.Uri);
        host.AddDefaultEndpoints();
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior() { HttpGetEnabled = true });

        foreach (var e in host.Description.Endpoints)
        {
            ((BasicHttpBinding)e.Binding).HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;
        }
        host.Open();

        //Trace.WriteLine("WCF Hello service running...");   
    }
```

when i try to access method defined in service i got bellow error

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.